# How many ways to choose $n$ distinct objects from a set of $m$ objects?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

So if a set contains $n$ objects, how many different ways would it be possible to pick distinct $m$ elements that are predetermined from a total of $c$ choices?

E. g. $\{1,2,3,4,5,.....,n\}$, how many ways would it be possible to pick $1$ and $2$ and $3$  (in this case $m=3$) if $c$ elements are picked (no duplicates)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have $n$ elements and some particular $m$ objects are fixed (they must be chosen).

There are a total of $c$ elements that need to be chosen with $m$ elements that must be there.

Now this means that there are $c-m$ elements that must be selected from $n-m$ elements.

$$\binom{n-m}{c-m}$$

Comment: Wow so simple yet so logical. Thanks.